# How to add an ID attribute to the anchor tag that is rendered from react-router link tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

> `// modules/App.js
>   <li><Link to="/about" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</Link></li>
>   <li><Link to="/repos" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Repos</Link></li>`

when inspecting the DOM using Chrome Developer tools I find that the Link Component renders an  tag. So I wan to know how to add an id attribute to the resulting a tag

`<a id="foo">`

> i have tried this but it didn't work :

`<li><Link id="foo" to="/about" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</Link></li>`

Comment: why u want to add id to a tag ?? any reason ?

Comment: I am working on an App which involves click tracking using Google Tag Manager which is being handled by another team. They Want us to add ID to all clickable links to be able to track clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can also pass props you'd like to be on the  such as a title, id, className, etc.

http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Which version of react-router are you using. Make sure that the id is not rendered, by inspecting the element using a dev console.

Answer (score 0):

It can be directly done by adding and ID attribute to the tha link tag:

> `<Link id="myId"></Link>`

the rendered anchor tag will conatin the ID attribute that was given to link tag.

You can also pass props you'd like to be on the  such as a title, id, className, etc.